# Python logging: how to destroy/rebuild a logger?

Tags: python, logging

I have written a short help- modul for logging parts my project. Logging to a file should be settable to debug, console always is to be set to warning level.

```
def __create_logger(log_level_console = logging.WARNING, log_level_file = logging.INFO, file_name = LOG_FILE_STANDARD):
    global LOGGER_NAME, LOG_IMMER
    global LOG_FORMAT_FILE_TIME, LOG_FORMAT_FILE_NACHRICHTEN
    global LOG_FORMAT_CONSOLE_TIME, LOG_FORMAT_CONSOLE_NACHRICHT

    logger_filename = file_name #'D:\\__TEMP__\\logging.txt'

    log_file_formatierer = logging.Formatter(LOG_FORMAT_FILE_NACHRICHTEN, LOG_FORMAT_FILE_TIME)
    log_file_handler = logging.FileHandler(logger_filename, mode = 'a')
    log_file_handler.setLevel(log_level_file)
    log_file_handler.setFormatter(log_file_formatierer)

    log_console_formatierer = logging.Formatter(LOG_FORMAT_CONSOLE_NACHRICHT, LOG_FORMAT_CONSOLE_TIME)
    log_console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    log_console_handler.setLevel(log_level_console)
    log_console_handler.setFormatter(log_console_formatierer)

    log = logging.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME)
    log.addHandler(log_console_handler)
    log.addHandler(log_file_handler)

    log.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)

    log.log(LOG_IMMER, 'logger angelegt, LogLevel (Konsole): {}, LogLevel (Datei): {}, Dateiname: {}'.format(log_level_console, log_level_file, file_name))
    return log
```

I use this that way

```
g_log = __create_logger(file_name = 'C:\\temp\\log.txt')
```

My Problem: If I do this more than once, for each I get a new output line.
That means:

```
g_log = __create_logger(file_name = 'C:\\temp\\log.txt')
g_log('Hallo')
... Hallo

g_log = __create_logger(file_name = 'C:\\temp\\log1.txt')
g_log = __create_logger(file_name = 'C:\\temp\\log2.txt')
g_log = __create_logger(file_name = 'C:\\temp\\log3.txt')

g_log('Hallo')

... Hallo
... Hallo
... Hallo
... Hallo
```

How can I "kill" g_log, before I generate a new logger?

Comment: Possible XY problem: why do you want to change the log file? You might want to use a `RotatingFileHandler` instead.

Comment: No, I want to use the module for more than 1 projects and sometimes I want to change the logfile for debugging. Something like g_log = __create_logger(file_name = ''C:\\temp\\log_debug.txt'', log_level_file = logging.DEBUG). But if I do this now I get every following message twice.